# Do 4.3 JellyBean apps work on 4.4 KitKat?

Tags: applications, 4.3-jelly-bean, 4.4-kitkat

I am an android developer and would like to upgrade my Nexus 7(2013, JellyBean 4.3) to KitKat 4.4.2.

My apps are all developed to work on 4.3 fine. I'm just wondering if my 4.3 apps will work when I upgrade. Does anyone know?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT** - I upgraded and all apps work fine, thanks for answers :D

**EDIT 2** - Actually, one of my Bluetooth Low Energy Apps does not work. Any Help? I have changed the targetSDK version to 19, but should I install the SDK for 19 as well?

Comment: Congrats! Make sure tha you thank answers with upvotes, and "Accept" the one you feel was most helpful. Questions for BLE should be asked in a new question.

Comment: I have not accepted because not all of my apps work. I do not think that BLE is the problem, but rather something else. If it is alright, I will leave the question longer and see if anyone else can help.

Comment: Did you try clearing the app data? Note that issues with app development are off-topic here.

Comment: I would say that the BLE bugs should be asked in a separate question nonetheless. The question here is "Will the apps work?" and both answers say "Most likely" - they are correct answers for the question asked. Our site's format doesn't work well with evolving threads - new issues are asked in new questions, like an issue-tracking system, so it's probably best for you if you close this one and ask the BLE questions on another question.

Answer (score 2):

There's no *gurantee* that they'll work, but API compatibility when upgrading is a standing tenet of Android. The odds are very high (above 90%) that they'll work no problem.

In the end, whether they work or not depends on **you, as the developer**. As an Android developer, you should probably read the documentation released with new API's for the features and methods you use.

One way or another, you may need to upgrade to 4.4 as soon as you can - in order to address potential bugs that may pop up for your users.

Comment: It's updating now, I'll edit answer if it works. Thanks :)

Comment: Excellent point about updating to identify and address potential bugs.  As a developer this is absolutely a high priority!

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be, yes, they will work.  As you know, when you develop an app you select the target Android build for your app, which is the lowest version of Android your app is "supposed" to work with.  That being the case, your apps are targeted for 4.3 and should easily work on 4.4.2.  Likewise, if you targeted 2.3 (as many devs do) your apps should still work.  It's not guaranteed, of course, but I think you will be fine.

As a side note, my Galaxy Note 2 recently received the new update and I haven't had any issues with apps that were installed on my phone, and I'm fairly certain they have not all been updated for KitKat.